# Learn Python The Hard Way #25

Tags: python

Going through the below, I have a question that I do not think has been answered yet (and is not called out in the lesson):

When I run either `print_first_word` or `print_last_word`, the resulting list is altered via the `.pop()` -  yet when I run the `print_first_and_last` function, the list remains unaltered after it has completed.  Since `print_first_and_last` is calling both `print_first_word` and `print_last_word`, each of which alter the list via a `.pop()`, why is the list unchanged after running `print_first_and_last`?

```
 def break_words(stuff):
    '''This function will break up words for us.'''
    stuff.split(' ')
    return stuff.split(' ')

def print_first_word(words):
    '''Prints the first word after popping it off.'''
    word = words.pop(0)
    print word

def print_last_word(words):
    '''Prints last word in the sentence'''
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print word  



def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    '''Prints first and last words in the sentence.'''
    words=break_words(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
```

Comment: String is passed by value (so a new copy is created), whereas a list is passed into a function by reference. In your example, the sentence will be unmodified if you call `print_first_and_last` since a new copy of the sentence is created. On the other hand, if you pass in a list to `print_first_and_last`, it will get modified.

Comment: @dparpyani: Everything is passed by reference in python... Some object just present an immutable interface.

Comment: Can you give an example of the input you would call `print_first_and_last()` with, and what about the specific output that you find surprising?

Comment: @sharth - Let's say I pass the string "Today I will go to the store" into the function via the variable Sentence (Sentence = "Today I will go to the Store").  The function will return Today and Store, which I would expect, but when I check to see what Sentence now contains, it's unaltered. This contrasts w/ running print_first_word (which first requires I run break_words on the variable Sentence to turn the string into a list)  as this function will remove the 1st part of the string via the pop(0) so that when I see what Sentence contains after running it, Sentence contains "I go to the store"

Comment: Ran out of space - but basically what I'm getting at is that since `print_first_and_last` calls both `print_first_word` and `print_last_word` which each alter the list via `.pop` - it doesn't make sense to me intuitively that `print_first_and_last` would leave the list unaltered.

Comment: @user3462509 it does *not* leave the list unaltered. After you "pop" the first and last items - the list is getting trimmed from both directions. Why do you think that it doesn't change the list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of `print_first_and_last()` is `words = break_words(sentence)`.

This line will create a **new object**! This new object will be a list containing each of the words in your sentence. This new (somewhat temporary) object, will be altered by `print_first_word()` and `print_last_word()`.

If we changed `print_first_and_last()` such that it printed more information, this might be clearer:

```
def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    words = break_words(sentence)

    print sentence, words
    print_first_word(words)
    print sentence, words
    print_last_word(words)
    print sentence, words
```

Comment: Both your answer and Alfasin were helpful, thank you.  I think I was having a difficult time conceptualizing global vs local.

Comment: So you practically copied my answer and extended your two sentences answer. That's pretty lame...

Comment: @alfasin: We were writing it up at more or less the exact same time.

Answer (score 1):

Running:

```
def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    '''Prints first and last words in the sentence.'''
    words=break_words(sentence)
    print words
    print_first_word(words)
    print words
    print_last_word(words)
    print words

print_first_and_last('This is the first test')
```

will output:

```
['This', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'test']
This
['is', 'the', 'first', 'test']
test
['is', 'the', 'first']
```

and as you can see, the list `words` obviously is altered!